# jQuery check if font weight is normal or bold

Tags: jquery, properties, fonts

I'm setting the font-weight property with the following code:

```
$(this).css({ 'font-weight': 'normal' });
```

Now i want to check if an element has bold or normal font-weight propety, how do i do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can get it using:

```
fontWeight = $(this).css('font-weight')
```

To compare:

```
if (fontWeight  == 'normal'|| fontWeight  == '400')
//or
if (fontWeight  == 'bold' || fontWeight  == '700')
```

Comment: I deleted my own answer because that depends on the browser. Firefox systematically returns numeric values for `font-weight` (`400` or `700`), Chrome does not.

Comment: I believe that should not be a problem as OP is only using normal/bold css property to set as font-weight.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if ($('#yourElement').css('font-weight') == 'normal') {
    // Your code if font-weight is normal
} else if($('#yourElement').css('font-weight') == 'bold') {
    // Your code if font-weight is bold
}
```