# I want to make a HTML text editor having bold functionality using window.getSelection

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, selection

It makes the whole text bold. I want only selected text to get bold (Strictly no exec Command)

```
let boldBtn = document.getElementById('Bold-Btn');
let boldClickListener = (event) =>
{
    event.preventDefault();
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    let final = `<span class="text-bold">${selection.focusNode.textContent}</span>`;
    selection.anchorNode.parentElement.innerHTML=final;
    console.log(selection);
};

boldBtn.addEventListener('click',boldClickListener);
```

Comment: check [`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) api https://codepen.io/chrisdavidmills/full/gzYjag/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this might be to do the following:

- Get the window selection.
- Convert the selection to a string to get the text.
- Create the element that will be bold.
- Replace the selected text contained in the `innerHTML` of the `parentElement` with the bolded element.

Example based on the code you provided:

```js
let boldBtn = document.getElementById('Bold-Btn');
let boldClickListener = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get selection
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  // Get string of text from selection
  let text = selection.toString();
  // Create bolded element that will replace the selected text
  let final = `<span class="text-bold">${text}</span>`;
  // Replace the selected text with the bolded element
  selection.anchorNode.parentElement.innerHTML = selection.anchorNode.parentElement.innerHTML.replace(text, final);
};

boldBtn.addEventListener('click', boldClickListener);
```

```css
.text-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
Test this text
</div>
<button id="Bold-Btn">
Bold
</button>
```

Note that you may want to add some more logic when creating your bold element to handle if any existing text is already bold.

Comment: can u help me with handling already existing bold elements? I.e to make them unbold. thanks in advance.

Comment: That's really a separate question. You should probably ask it in a separate post. But these answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43064500 and https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/19779-if-text-is-bold-function

Comment: as far as I can tell it won't work though if the text obtained with getSelection will contain some other html tags underneath, e.g. <div>Test<span>th</span><p>is</p><div>tex</div>t</div>. You'll hopefully never get it like this though